# Can't run the example of flask-assistant python library

Tags: python, flask, assistant

I am trying to run `flask-assistant` library for Google Assistant development. I followed the instructions from [here](https://flask-assistant.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html).

I installed the `flask-assistant` library in a `virtualenv`. 
My `webhook.py` looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_assistant import Assistant, ask, tell

app = Flask(__name__)
assist = Assistant(app, route='/', project_id='GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID')


@assist.action('greeting')
def greet_and_start():
    speech = "Hey! Are you male or female?"
    return ask(speech)

@assist.action("give-gender")
def ask_for_color(gender):
    if gender == 'male':
        gender_msg = 'Sup bro!'
    else:
        gender_msg = 'Haay gurl!'

    speech = gender_msg + ' What is your favorite color?'
    return ask(speech)

@assist.action('give-color', mapping={'color': 'sys.color'})
def ask_for_season(color):
    speech = 'Ok, {} is an okay color I guess'.format(color)
    return ask(speech)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I did everything as it said but at the step where I have to run `schema webhook.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexmarginean/Documents/Projects/travelrr-google-assistant/venv/bin/schema", line 7, in <module>
    from api_ai.cli import schema
  File "/Users/alexmarginean/Documents/Projects/travelrr-google-assistant/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/api_ai/cli.py", line 15, in <module>
    "Schema generation and management is not yet available for Dialogflow V2, please define intents and entities in the Dialogflow console"
DeprecationWarning: Schema generation and management is not yet available for Dialogflow V2, please define intents and entities in the Dialogflow console
```

I tried to switch to BETA V2 and V1 but problem is still there. I also checked if my `tokens` are right and they are. I also tried to update the `schema` library but no luck. I'm not sure how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting an [issue](https://github.com/treethought/flask-assistant/issues/113) from the flask-assistant project's GitHub repository, the owner/developer of flask-assistant says (as of 1 March 2019):

> [He has] not yet updated the schema functionality to support the dialogflow V2 API.

Looks like there is no support yet for V2 API.